# Read a .txt file using another class then login Java

Tags: java, text, authentication

I begin to learn java one month ago and today I want create a login code in java.
Basically I want to read a .txt file, which contains login informations (username and password), using another class and compare them with login informations given by the user in the main class. 
But when I try to read the .txt I have an error of type from the  UserList class with (incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String):
" loginList.add(new User(res[0], Integer.parseInt(res[1])));".

Moreover I have difficulties  to code the comparator. To be honest I don't even know where to begin to code it...
Thanks in advance for your help.

*Main*

```
public class BoiteDeJeux {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username;
        String password;
        System.out.print("Enter your username");
        username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your password");
        password = input.nextLine();
        loginCheck(username, password);

    }
```

*User*

```
package boitedejeux;

public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

*UserList*

```
public class UserList {

    private ArrayList<User> loginList;

    public UserList(ArrayList<User> loginList) {
        Scanner sc;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("F:\\Cours\\[ISIS 2A]\\Projet Programmation\\BoiteDeJeux\\src\\boitedejeux\\Logins.txt"));
            String ligne = sc.nextLine();
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                ligne = sc.nextLine();
                String[] res = ligne.split(",");
                loginList.add(new User(res[0], Integer.parseInt(res[1])));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
}
```

*Login.txt*

```
Test, Password
Test2, Password2
```

Comment: "I have an error" and "I have difficulties" are not useful problem descriptions. What specific problems are you facing?

Comment: There could be a number of things wrong, it likely depends on the contents of `Logins.txt`. It could be that `res` only has 1 element (no commas in file), or that res[1] is not an integer (so the second value in `Logins.txt` is a word or something else). Is this a run time, or compiler time issue? What error message did you receive?

Comment: @shmosel: The error that I have is that it say that of incompatible type (int cannot be converted into string). As for the comparator I don't even know where to begin to do it.

Comment: @rtpax: My logins.txt is like that:                                                        
Test, Password
Test2, Password2

Comment: What's not clear about the error? And what comparator are you talking about?

Comment: @shmosel: When I'm talking about comparator, I'm talking about the creation of a method that check if the username and password given by the user correspond to one in the login.txt. Concerning the error, I basically don't understand what I have to do.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need a comparator for that. The error should be self-explanatory, and you already know what to do: exactly what you're doing with `res[1]`.

Comment: @shmosel: You're totally right, thanks ! Now I will try again to do the comparator, when I finish it I will post it.